# Как обновить Android Gradle Plugin?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Как обновить *Android Gradle* плагин?

> Error:Gradle 2.4 requires Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 (or newer)  but project is using version 1.1.3.
>   Please use Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 or newer.

пробую вручную в *dependencies* поменять версию с 1.1.3 на 1.2.0. и синхронизировать — не выходит.

Answer (score 2):

В файл `build.gradle`, который находится на уровне проекта, а не на уровне папки `app`, напишите следующие данные в блок

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
```

Сихнхронизация проходит успешно